# send data while redirect to view in django

Tags: python, django, django-views

Is it possible to send data while to redirecting to another view?

For example:-

```
def social_user():
//do something here
 return redirect('name of the view',{'variable':'value'})
```

or any other alternative to exchange data between a function and view function.

Comment: What kind of data? If it's a simple type like a number, you can pass it in the url itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to send data to the resulting destination, but first you should understand how redirects work.

When the server redirects, it just sets the `Location` header telling the browser which page to fetch next.

```
Location: /foo.html
```

Since the body is completely ignored even if present, you must somehow pass data via the HTTP headers.

#### 1) Query Parameters

The easiest way is to use query (GET) parameters which you can then read from the destination page:

```
Location: /foo.html?username=bob
```

The downside is that the user can easily see and modify this value.

#### 2) Cookies

The session, which is determined by cookies, is another place to store temporary data. But this has several downsides:

- It is not tied to any request, so you all consequent request will have access to the data until you delete it.
- It doesn't work if the user has disabled cookies. On the other hand query parameters always work.

---

If you choose the first option, you may need to write some of your own code since Django doesn't seem to offer a convenient method to do this (someone correct me if I'm wrong). Here's a sample function that wraps the functionality:

```
def redirect_with_query(path, query=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if query is None:
        query = {}

    url = resolve_url(path, *args, **kwargs)

    if len(query):
        q_dict = QueryDict(mutable=True)
        q_dict.update(query)
        url += '?' + q_dict.urlencode()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Comment: Django has a builtin way to encode parameters for a URL. Please refer to QueryDict.urlencode function in: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/

Comment: Thanks, I thought there must be a better way. I'll update the answer when I have access to a python install with django to test correctness. Alternatively, you may want to update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**First Solution::**

If you have access to the request variable in `social_user`, you can simply make use of sessions. Sessions are the best way to transfer data between 2 views.

```
def social_user(request):
    request.session['variable'] = 'value'
    return redirect('name of the view')
```

Then inside your view, you can access this variable using `request.session.get('variable')`

**Second Solution::**

In case you can't set session variables, send them as query parameters.

```
def social_user():
    //do something here
     return redirect("your_view/?variable=value")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Build a "mock django request" manually and call the view directly
2. Use query parameters

Answer (score 0):

Use [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render) and pass the variable via `context`:

```
def social_user(request)
    // do something here
    return render(request, template_name='template.html', context={'variable': 'value'})
```